Integral $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}\,dx$
I am self-studying how to solve integrals with gamma-functions. I tried to solve following integral: $$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}\,dx$$
This was my attempt: let $x={u}^\frac{1}{4}$, thus we get following integral $\frac{1}{4} \int_0^1 \frac{{u}^\frac{-3}{4}}{\sqrt{1-u}}du$. After the simple substitution t=1-u the  integral takes the form $\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 {(1-t)}^\frac{-3}{4}{t}^\frac{-1}{2}dt$.
This is equivalent to $\frac{1}{4}\mathcal{B}(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2})$ which can be expressed through $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})}{4\Gamma(\frac{3}{4})}$. However this might not seem to be the correct answer. My textbook says that the correct answer is $\frac{{(\Gamma(\frac{1}{4}))}^2}{4\sqrt{2\pi}}$.
Could anyone help me to find my mistake?

Diverges !!!.$\mbox{}$

doesnt the beta function converge for positive values?

because of the substitution $x={u}^\frac{1}{4}$

welcome to the site. I think you miswrote your integral as $\int_0^1\frac{1}{1-x^4}\,dx$, which does diverge, but looking at your other work and your textbook you intended $\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}\,dx$ - which converges.
Your answer is also correct; it's just that: $$\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(1/4)}{4\Gamma(3/4)}=\frac{\Gamma(1/4)^2}{4\sqrt{2\pi}}$$Are the same. To see why, we can do some rearrangement and find it is equivalent to check: $$\sqrt{2}\cdot\pi=\Gamma(1/4)\Gamma(3/4)$$This is true because of the reflection formula $\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s)=\pi\csc\pi s$, for $s$ a non-integral complex number. If we allow $s:=1/4$, we obtain exactly what we want since $1-1/4=3/4$ and $\csc\pi/4=\frac{1}{\sin\pi/4}=\frac{1}{1/\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{2}$.

thanks! that makes sense. i miswrote the integral!
